# JAX-RS: Multiple ExceptionMappers handling the same Exception

Tags: java, jax-rs, guice, resteasy, exceptionmapper

We have two version of APIs in a monolith architecture. Each one of them has a GenericExceptionHandler which extends JAX-RS's ExceptionMapper. Once I bind the ExceptionMappers as providers for the APIs using Guice, the second ExceptionMapper takes over the mapping of exceptions for the first one, which is not desired.

Is there any way to make them co-exist, for example all the exceptions that are thrown inside the v1 api to be dealt with by the first Exception Mapper and all the exceptions that are thrown inside the v2 api to be dealt with by the first ExceptionMapper.

```
    //Guice configuration Class
    private static final List<Class> v2Providers = Arrays.asList(
            ...,
            GenericExceptionMapperV2.class,
           ...,
    );
    
    private static final List<Class> v1Providers = Arrays.asList(
            ...,
            GenericExceptionMapperV1.class,
           ...,
    );

    private void bindV2() { // same for v1
        install(new v2ImplModule());
        List<Class> providers = getProvidersBound(v2Providers);
        String resources = Stream.of(... // classes)
                .map(Class::getName)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
        final Map<String, String> initParams = computeInitParams(resources, providers, v2path);
        serve(v2path).with(new HttpServletDispatcher(), initParams);
    }

    private Map<String, String> computeInitParams(String resources, List<Class> providers, String path) {
        final Map<String, String> initParams = new HashMap<>();
        String prods = providers.stream().map(Class::getName).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
        initParams.put(PREFIX_KEY, path);
        initParams.put(RESOURCE_KEY, resources);
        initParams.put(PROVIDER_KEY, prods);
        return initParams;
    }
```

I've tried

```
        Multibinder<ExceptionMapper<Exception>> multibinder =
                Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), new TypeLiteral<ExceptionMapper<Exception>>() {});

        multibinder.addBinding().to(GenericExceptionMapperV1.class);
        multibinder.addBinding().to(GenericExceptionMapperV2.class);
```

but it still doesn't work

Comment: JAX-RS doesn't support this, but you can create a wrapper that checks the path of the (injected) current request and then delegates to either instance. I don't think you can let JAX-RS inject anything in these, but you can turn them into regular classes and pass along injected fields to the mapping methods.